# Get Week start and end of next 10 week

Tags: php, date

I've been using a modified function I've found but it still needs something to fix it.

```
public static function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
    $ret = Array();
    for($i = 0; $i<=9;$i++)
    {
        $ret[$i]['week_start'] = $dto->format('d/m/Y');
        $dto->modify('+6 days');
        $ret[$i]['week_end'] = $dto->format('d/m/Y');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Using

```
$week_array = class::getStartAndEndDate(date('W'),date('Y'));
echo '<pre>';print_r($week_array);exit;
```

I get :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 10/02/2014
            [week_end] => 16/02/2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 16/02/2014
            [week_end] => 22/02/2014
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 22/02/2014
            [week_end] => 28/02/2014
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 28/02/2014
            [week_end] => 06/03/2014
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 06/03/2014
            [week_end] => 12/03/2014
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 12/03/2014
            [week_end] => 18/03/2014
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 18/03/2014
            [week_end] => 24/03/2014
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 24/03/2014
            [week_end] => 30/03/2014
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 30/03/2014
            [week_end] => 05/04/2014
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [week_start] => 05/04/2014
            [week_end] => 11/04/2014
        )

)
```

It is working for this week (Monday here) and we get 10/02/2014 - 16/02/2014 but the second week instead of being 17/02/2014 - 23/02/2014 is actually 16/02/2014 - 22/02/2014.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another `+1 day`  like this:

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
    $ret = Array();
    for($i = 0; $i<=9;$i++)
    {
        $ret[$i]['week_start'] = $dto->format('d/m/Y');
        $dto->modify('+6 days');
        $ret[$i]['week_end'] = $dto->format('d/m/Y');
        $dto->modify('+1 day');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```